# Ubuntu dropping to shell on 15.04

Tags: 15.04, virtualbox

I installed Xubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu
```

Then, I reset the machine (I'm in virtualbox) and this when the magic happens.

[image]

How do I get the graphical part of the computer back?

Comment: How did you "reset" your VM? Apparently your virtual hard drive got corrupted by that.

Comment: I shutdown then went back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drive is probably corrupt.

What might fix this is re-installing Ubuntu.

TO DO THIS:

1. Set the boot order as DISK,FLOPPY,HARD DRIVE (In settings for VBOX)
2. Insert the disk for the Ubuntu installation
3. Reboot
4. Setup the installation. You'll get an option to reinstall Ubuntu without harming your files
5. Reboot and you should be done.

NOTE: THIS ISNT TESTED. :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was unable to mount your [virtual] drive!

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/35a61b3c-ab96......3cc
```

list the device area to see what is there: `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/*` and look in the file table: `cat /etc/fstab` and see if the disk above is listed.  If they are different, you can edit the file `/etc/fstab` to change the disk label to the one that is listed with `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/`  You can then try to mount the drive.

Comment: can you dumb it down a (big) bit?

Comment: Both of the directories are invalid. They don't exist.

Comment: Sorry!  I'm afraid it will take a lot of detail to find out the cause and solution to your problem and is beyond my abilities to help. Perhaps someone else will be able to supply a better solution. As Takkat commented above, perhaps the disk was corrupted.